# in6_addr in GCC 4

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I see code like following :  (legecy code in the project I am working on)

```
#if __GNUC__ > 3
    .ipv6_addr = {.__in6_u = {.__u6_addr32 = {0, 0, 0, 0}}}
#else
    .ipv6_addr = {.in6_u = {.u6_addr32 = {0, 0, 0, 0}}}
#endif
```

where "ipv6_addr" is in type of struct in6_addr.  I don't understand why its member in6_u would change to "**in6_u" if __GNUC** > 3.

My question is:  why / when  GCC version could impact the name of the field in struct in6_addr ?

Thanks.

Update: my host system has GCC 4.1.2, but the in6_addr was defined as :

```
in /usr/include/netinet/in.h

/* IPv6 address */
struct in6_addr
  {
    union
      {
        uint8_t u6_addr8[16];
        uint16_t u6_addr16[8];
        uint32_t u6_addr32[4];
      } in6_u;
#define s6_addr                 in6_u.u6_addr8
#define s6_addr16               in6_u.u6_addr16
#define s6_addr32               in6_u.u6_addr32
  };
```

And gcc version is:

```
$/usr/bin/gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --disable-plugin --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.4.2-gcj-1.4.2.0/jre --with-cpu=generic --host=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-50)
```

Comment: You should also look at the libc header defining that struct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure definition of concern here, `struct in6_addr`, comes from the C runtime library (in `<netinet/in.h>`).  The C runtime library is usually tightly coupled with the *operating system* in use, but *not* the C *compiler* in use.  This is especially true for the C compilers that define `__GNUC__` to any value (there are at least three of these: GCC, clang, and icc); these compilers are designed to be usable with many different OSes and runtimes.  Therefore, in principle, testing `__GNUC__` does not tell you anything useful about structure definitions that come from the runtime.

I suspect that the authors of this "legacy code" tested on two different Linux distributions, noted an *accidental* correlation between the value of `__GNUC__` and the contents of `<netinet/in.h>`, and didn't bother looking for a more correct way to make their code compile.

You should replace the entire conditional with this:

```
.ipv6_addr = IN6ADDR_ANY_INIT;
```

The macro `IN6ADDR_ANY_INIT` is required by the relevant standard ([POSIX.1-2008 spec for `<netinet/in.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/netinet_in.h.html)) to be usable as an initializer for a variable of type `in6_addr`, setting that variable to the IPv6 wildcard address, which is all-bits-zero.  So it will have the same effect without requiring any `#ifdef`s at all.

---

To illustrate that `#if __GNUC__ > 3` is the wrong test to apply here, here are three different definitions of `struct in6_addr`, all taken from systems where you might reasonably encounter *both* `__GNUC_==3` and `__GNUC__==4` (the 3.x series is getting a little old nowadays, but I still run into it from time to time).

#### GNU libc 2.17

```
struct in6_addr
  {
    union
      {
        uint8_t __u6_addr8[16];
#if defined __USE_MISC || defined __USE_GNU
        uint16_t __u6_addr16[8];
        uint32_t __u6_addr32[4];
#endif
      } __in6_u;
  };
```

#### NetBSD 6.1

```
struct in6_addr {
        union {
                __uint8_t   __u6_addr8[16];
                __uint16_t  __u6_addr16[8];
                uint32_t  __u6_addr32[4];
        } __u6_addr;                    /* 128-bit IP6 address */
};
```

#### Windows 7 (official SDK; perversely does not provide `netinet/in.h`):

```
struct in6_addr {
    union {
        UCHAR     Byte[16];
        USHORT    Word[8];
    } u;
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. I agreed. However, what puzzled me is that my host system has GCC 4.1.2 but the <netinet/in.h> defines the in6_addr different from what you listed.

Comment: Moreover, gcc is just a compiler,  why its version is related to the definition of in6_addr at all?  The in6_addr definition is decided by the Linux version, or libc?  (is libc part of gcc?) .  Thanks.

Comment: By the way, I updated the original question with the outputs from my host system. Thanks.

Comment: The version of GCC is *not* related to the definition of in6_addr.  That was the point I was trying to make.  The in6_addr definition is provided by the C library, which is a separate project.  For Linux, the most commonly used C library is GNU libc, but there are others.  You have a different C library than me.

Comment: Does the revised answer clarify things for you?